# Mapbox is only displayed when I reload the page

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, reload, mapbox

I have a weird problem I don't manage to find answer for:
I've setup mapbox so it displays on my website. I use [Koken](http://koken.me/) as framework, so a few tag are from it, but it's basically similar to classic html. Here is the content of my file:

```
    <koken:include file="inc/header.html" />

    <koken:head>
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="{{ site.title }}" />
        <meta property="og:title" content="{{ content.title|content.filename strip_html="true" }}" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="{{ content.caption strip_html="true" }}" />
        <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="{{ content.presets.medium_large.url }}" />
        <meta property="og:image:width" content="{{ content.presets.medium_large.width }}" />
        <meta property="og:image:height" content="{{ content.presets.medium_large.height }}" />
        <meta property="og:url" content="{{ content.url }}" />
        <koken:content_image>
            <koken:not empty="profile.twitter">
                <meta name="twitter:card" content="photo" />
                <meta name="twitter:site" content="@{{ profile.twitter }}" />
                <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@{{ profile.twitter }}" />
            </koken:not>
        </koken:content_image>

        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>World map</title>
        <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
        <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.4/mapbox.js'></script>
        <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.4/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <style>
          body { margin:0; padding:0; }
          #map-website { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height: 960px}
        </style>

    </koken:head>

<body>

<div id='map-website'></div>

    <script>
      L.mapbox.accessToken= 'my_token';
      var map = L.mapbox.map('map-website', 'mapbox.streets');

    </script>

</body>

<koken:include file="inc/footer.html" />
```

Super simple, that comes straight out of mapbox exemples. The issue I'm facing is that when I click on my website ([romdicos.phography](http://romdicos.phography)). And then click on the /map link, the page loads indefinitely and nothing never happens and the debug bar tells me that L is undefined.
However, if I click in the address bar and hit enter, then the map displays.

What am I doing wrong?
Many thanks in advance...

Comment: Maybe try adding something to set the view like: 

var map = L.mapbox.map('map-website', 'mapbox.streets')
    .setView([40, -74.50], 9);   If you're getting an error that L is undefined then that means that mapbox.js isn't loading before it gets to the mapping code below.  Maybe check your framework to make sure that library gets loaded properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The setView doesn't change anything unfortunately... And I do have the L is undefined error in the debug console. I suppose you're right saying mapbox.js isn't loaded correctly. But I have no idea how this happens as reloading the page loads the library correctly. The workaround I found consist as force the page to reload by adding: `code`
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){    
    if(document.URL.indexOf("#")==-1){
        url = document.URL+"#";
        location = "#";
        location.reload();
    }});
</script>`code`